# Format range as table

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

I have a set of data that changes in length. I would like to make a macro that does various things, including making the entire data set a table?

Using Selection.End(xlToRight) and xlToDown to select the data works, but when the recorded macro converts it to a table it does it only to the selected range.

Here is what the record function gives me:

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$H$26095"), , xlYes).Name _
    = "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
```

Is there a way to make the range dynamic based on the range selection above?

Comment: Using `Selection`, but really you should [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: So variables are way beyond my ability. How would I use Selection?

Comment: You would change `Range("$A$1:$H$26095")` to `Selection` but highly recommend you read the linked thread regardless.

Answer (score 0):

### Range to Table

- Various errors will occur if you already have added the table, or the table overlaps with another, etc. So I added a procedure that deletes all tables in the worksheet `Sheet1` in the workbook containing this code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RangeToTable()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rg, , xlYes)
    tbl.Name = "Table1"
End Sub

Sub DeleteAllTables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        tbl.Delete
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

If you want to kind of 'stick to your guns' (not recommended), you could use the following one-liner:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
```

There is no need to select anything.